# publish_actions Permission on C# Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, facebook

I'm developing an C# Windows Forms Application for a customer where there is a need to the final user to share a post on his Facebook wall. I was able to post on my own wall, since I'm the owner / developer of the application but when I was setting up the Facebook Application permissions, I was unable to submit the application for reviewing because I have to "Select a Plattform first".
The thing is, there is no suitable plattform for Windows Forms applications. This is an application that won't be in Windows Marketplace or anything similar.
How am I supposed to procede in this case?
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you found a solution? I have the smae problem